# Elixir Plug gzip not working for pngs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I have

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/pros",
  from: :zipbooks,
  gzip: true,
  cache_control_for_etags: "public, max-age=604800",
  only: ~w(css assets fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

and my `js` `css` and `svg` files are being served with `content-encoding:gzip` but my png files, served the same way, are not.

Here's an example of an svg and how its gzipped:

[image]

and heres a png

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.png` to `gzippable_exts` config as mentioned in the docs [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/phoenix_mix_tasks.html#phoenix-specific-mix-tasks).

> We can optionally determine which files should be gzipped by using the
>   :gzippable_exts option in the config file:
>
> ```
> config :phoenix, :gzippable_exts, ~w(.js .css)
> ```

It doesn't make sense to compress png files though since they're already compressed which is why the [default `gzippable_exts`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/b6ba07c8d3c0b1c08f63f4fa11b07f66fe7183d0/mix.exs#L54) doesn't include it.

Comment: You both answered the question and told me what I really needed to realize! "It doesn't make sense to compress png files" Thanks!